# Как получить массив индексов если для элементов массива выполняется условие? Python, Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, оптимизация

И вот я снова здесь, я хочу ускорить, улучшить, "занумпаить", то есть сделать без цикла и по `numpy`-евски, вот эту конструкцию:

```py
translated_vecs = np.array([[[ 1.94371022,  2.,          5.47115878],
                            [-0.70673817, -1.,          7.91556533],
                            [ 0.97185511,  5.,          5.23557939]],

                           [[-2.0908572,  -1.5,         9.38073238],
                            [-0.82569494,  0.88,        8.91568996],
                            [-1.09956499,  1.2,        9.62102335]]])

normals = np.array([[-0.5067397,  -0.22941573, -0.83101341],
                    [ 0.81391176, -0.34070593,  0.47060292]])

# то что идет дальше надо как-то преобразовать в numpy код

indexes = []

for i, translated_veс in enumerate(translated_vecs):
    normal = normals[i]

    if translated_veс[0] @ normal <= 0: #   -5.990392944695866  в первой итерации и  3.2238856963428164 во второй
        indexes.append(i)

# В данном примере выходит, что массив indexes будет таким [0]

# дальше идут мои преобразования с projection_vecs[indexes]
```

Comment: я над этим как раз и работаю) @MaxU

Comment: @MaxU Я добавил примеры данных

Comment: @MaxU в данном примере выходит пустой массив индексов, в вопросе я это указал

Comment: @MaxU да, я поставил индекс ноль не в том месте :/

Comment: дайте знать когда приведете __воспроизводимый__ пример данных...

Comment: @MaxU Да, я привел пример данных

Comment: вы пробовали запускать код из вопроса в новом терминале?

Comment: @MaxU, да я исправил ошибку с русской "с"

Comment: т.е. в `translated_vec` - вы проверяете только первый элемент `translated_vec[0]` - остальные вас не интересуют?

Comment: @MaxU нет, я проверяю первый элемент у ```translated_vec``` в цикле, у меня вот такая строчка ```for i, translated_veс in enumerate(translated_vecs):```

Comment: в цикле вы используете переменную `translated_vec` (размерность: `(3, 3)`), потом вы умножаете первую строчку `translated_vec[0]` (размерность: `(3, )`) на `normal`. Так вот я и спрашиваю используете ли вы оставшиеся две строки из переменной `translated_vec`?

Comment: @MaxU в этом цикле нет, но эти две строки используются в других фрагментах кода, например, для того чтобы выявить ```projection_vecs```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
indexes = np.where(np.diag(translated_vecs[:, 0, :] @ normals.T) <= 0)[0]
```

данное решение нужно будет перепроверить на б**о**льшем примере данных...

Comment: Да! Спасибо огромное! Это именно то что мне было нужно!

Comment: Хорошо, до меня туго доходит по жизни, но впредь буду бережнее относится к вашему и моему времени